# TIdFTP in a thread not firing Work method

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

I've got a VCL application written in Embarcadero's C++ 10 Seattle.  The main thread spawns a thread to run the TIdFTP functionality since the Get method indefinitely hangs if the connection is lost during the transfer.  The idea is to detect if the connection has hung, orphan the thread, and spawn a "retry".  My problem is I've declared the object in the thread's h file as well as the methods that should fire (WorkBegin, WorkEnd, Work, etc) like follows....

```
class FTPThread : public TThread
{
protected:
    void __fastcall Execute();
    void __fastcall UpdateUI();
public:
    __fastcall FTPThread(bool CreateSuspended);
    String FTPhostname;
    String FTPusername;
    String FTPpassword;
    String remoteDir;
    String localDir;
    String localTempDir;
    String fileName;
    TIdFTP *FTPClnt;
    void __fastcall FTPClntWorkBegin(TObject *ASender, TWorkMode AWorkMode, __int64 AWorkCountMax);
    void __fastcall FTPClntWorkEnd(TObject *ASender, TWorkMode AWorkMode);
    void __fastcall FTPClntWork(TObject *ASender, TWorkMode AWorkMode, __int64 AWorkCount);
    void __fastcall FTPClntAfterGet(TObject *ASender, TStream *AStream);

};
```

I then implemented the Work functions in the thread's cpp file like this.....

```
void __fastcall FTPThread::UpdateUI()
{
    if (FrmFTP) {
        //FrmFTP->FTPProg->Max = fileSizeBytes;
        FrmFTP->FTPProg->Position = ftpProgress;
        FrmFTP->BringToFront();
        Application->ProcessMessages();
    }
}

void __fastcall FTPThread::FTPClntWorkBegin(TObject *ASender,
    TWorkMode AWorkMode, __int64 AWorkCountMax) {
    ftpProgress = 0;
    if (FrmFTP) {
        FrmFTP->FTPProg->Max = fileSizeBytes;
    }
    Synchronize(&UpdateUI);
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall FTPThread::FTPClntWorkEnd(TObject *ASender,
    TWorkMode AWorkMode)

{
    if (FrmFTP) {
        ftpProgress = FrmFTP->FTPProg->Max;
    }
    Synchronize(&UpdateUI);
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall FTPThread::FTPClntWork(TObject *ASender, TWorkMode AWorkMode,
    __int64 AWorkCount)

{
   ftpProgress = AWorkCount;
   Synchronize(&UpdateUI);
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall FTPThread::FTPClntAfterGet(TObject *ASender,
    TStream *AStream) {
    ftpCompletionStatus = 1;
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

None of these methods are ever fired as the Get begins, transfers, and completes.  Any idea why they wouldn't fire?  The same functionality on my main thread worked fine.  I feel like I'm somehow not trying these methods I've implemented to the TIdFTP Object but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the Get method indefinitely hangs if the connection is lost during the transfer.

It should fail eventually.  It just might take awhile for the OS to actually detect the lost connection and invalidate the open sockets so I/O operations start reporting errors.  If you don't want to wait that long, make sure to set the `ReadTimeout` property to a reasonable timeout (`TIdFTP` set it to 1 minute by default), as well as the `TransferTimeout` property (infinite by default).

> The idea is to detect if the connection has hung, orphan the thread, and spawn a "retry".

**NEVER** "orphan" a thread.  You could simply have the main thread call `TIdFTP`'s `Abort()` and `Disconnect()` methods instead, to terminate a transfer in progress and close the command socket, respectively.

> My problem is I've declared the object in the thread's h file as well as the methods that should fire (WorkBegin, WorkEnd, Work, etc) like follows....

*DO NOT* call `Application->ProcessMessages()` inside of a synched method.  The method is already running inside of a main thread message handler, just exit the synched method so control returns to the main message loop.

Also, your `OnWork...` handlers are directly accessing `FrmFTP->FTPProg->Max` from outside of the main thread.  Those accesses need to be synched as well.  *ANYTHING* that touches the main UI needs to be synched.

> None of these methods are ever fired as the Get begins, transfers, and completes. Any idea why they wouldn't fire?

Did you hook them up to begin with?  Presumably `FTPClnt` is being created in `FTPThread::Execute()`, but is it assigning your handlers to the `FTPClnt->OnWork...` events after creating `FTPClnt`?  They are not going to hook themselves up for you, you have to do it yourself, eg:

```
FTPClnt = new TIdFTP;
FTPClnt->OnWorkBegin = &FTPClntWorkBegin;
FTPClnt->OnWorkEnd = &FTPClntWorkEnd;
FTPClnt->OnWork = &FTPClntWork;
```

> The same functionality on my main thread worked fine.

If you drop a `TIdFTP` object on a Form at design-time, and assign its `OnWork...` events within the Object Inspector, then the DFM streaming system hooks up the event handlers for you when the Form is created at runtime.

Simply *declaring* event handlers is not enough.  Somebody (you or the DFM) has to actually *hook them up* at runtime.

Comment: Thanks Remy!  I have transfer timeout set to 5 seconds and the Get method still never returns.  It hung all night last night on my dev system and never executed the line of code after the Get call.  It simply never returns which is why I am having to put the FTP software into a thread so my main thread is not stopped permanently.

Comment: I had the TIdFTP object on my main form and figured the object inspector was hooking up the event handler for me but didn't quite know how.  Thanks for the sample code....I'll add that into my thread execute method where the FTPClnt is being created.

Comment: When you say all the accesses need synced, do you just mean anything that touches a form needs to be moved to the Syncronize method? Thanks again!

Comment: @martinarcher yes, that is what I mean. As for the timeouts, it definitely should not be waiting all night, unless the data is transferring very slowly but not slow enough to elapse the timeouts. Have you verified with a packet sniffer that all of the data is being transferred and a final response is being received?

Comment: "*I know it's not being received*" - then the `ReadTimeout` should be kicking in (make sure it is not set to infinite), unless the socket is frozen at the OS layer (I have seen cases where the socket API `select()` function can deadlock on old systems). "*I am disconnecting the link to the embedded controller*" - then you are disconnecting the sockets abnormally. The OS cannot react to abnormal disconnects in a timely manner, so it may take a long time for it to even see the disconnect.

Comment: "*The TIdFTP client Get then hangs*" - at what stage, though? While the data socket is still actively transferring data, or after the data socket has been closed and `Get()` is waiting for the final response on the command socket? Have you stepped into `Get()` with the debugger?

Comment: One thing you can try - set `TIdFTP.NATKeepAlive.UseKeepAlive` to false (not true), and then after connecting to the server, call `TIdFTP.Socket.Binding.SetKeepAliveValues()` to manually enable keepalives on the command socket for the lifetime of the connection, and use the `TIdFTP.OnDataChannelCreate` event to call `ADataChannel.Socket.Binding.SetKeepAliveValues()` to enable keepalives on the data socket during transfers. That might help the OS handle this situation better.

Comment: I have not debugged the Get method.  I'm not sure what you mean by terminating the socket abnormally.  I can simulate an FTP failure in two ways....unplug the network cable between the two boxes or reboot the embedded controller that is running the server.  The same result happens....get never returns.  It could be the OS not reporting the connection loss.  I am explicitly setting the TransferTimeout to 5 seconds....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122447/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-martinarcher).